# C++ MFC double to CString

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Sorry for my English.

I need to convert double value to CString, because i need to do AfxMessageBox(double_value);

I find this:

```
std::ostringstream ost;
ost << double_value;
std::cout << "As string: " << ost.str() << std::endl;
//AfxMessageBox(ost.str()); - Does not work.
```

How i can do this?

Comment: of course it wont work - AfxMessageBox expects a double, why should it be able to get a cstring?

Comment: AfxMessageBox does not expect a double...

Comment: @zmbq doesnt AfxMessageBox(*double_value*); not suggest it expects a double?

Comment: AfxMessageBox expects CString:
AfxMessageBox("Text");
It is not double

Comment: Actually AfxMessageBox expects LPCTSTR, not CString, but the latter has fine implicit conversion so it would work. Your trial implies you have UNICODE config, what causes the error. You can use AfxMessageBoxA instead of AfxMessageBox. Certainly using the accepted answer is also okay.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AfxMessageBox` expects a `CString` object, so format the double into a `CString` and pass that:

```
CString str;
str.Format("As string: %g", double);
AfxMessageBox(str);
```

Edit: If you want the value displayed as an integer (no value after decimal point) then use this instead:

```
str.Format("As string: %d", (int)double);
```

Comment: Big thx, it is work. Please, if you know - tell me how can i do crop/cut part of CString. I have 12.09 value, i need 12 value.

Comment: Use `%d` instead of `%g`, it should give you the integer value.

Comment: %d give me this: As string: -1546188226

Comment: @user2254511 Have you solved your problem?  (casting to `int` is the key).

Answer (score 0):

That's because ost.str() is not a CString, but rather a C++ string object. You need to convert that to CString: `new CString(ost.str())`.

Comment: Sorry, im beginner
CString sss = new CString(ost.str());
Not work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Unicode settings you need

```
std::ostringstream ost;
ost << std::setprecision(2) << double_value;
std::cout << "As string: " << ost.str() << std::endl;
AfxMessageBox(ost.str().c_str());
```

or

```
std::wostringstream ost;
ost << std::setprecision(2) << double_value;
std::wcout << L"As string: " << ost.str() << std::endl;
AfxMessageBox(ost.str().c_str());
```

This is needed because CString has a constructor for `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`. There is no constructor for std::string or std::wstring. You can also use the CString.Format which has the same not typesave problems like sprintf.

**Be aware that double conversion is locale dependent. Decimal seperator will depend on your location.**